# Running more than 12 transactions at once using Promise.all throws error

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, transactions, prisma

I have a function for my api which uses $transaction inside of it.
I am testing it using Vitest, and for simulating requests, I've run the function 20 times using Promise.all, like so:

###### the function

```
const verifyEmail = (data) => {
    return prisma.$transaction(async tx => {
       // some reading
       // some updaing
    })
}
```

###### test

```
test("run verifyEmail multiple times", async () => {
    await Promise.all(myCredentials.map(data => verifyEmail(data)))
})
```

and the error I get:

```
Transaction API error: Unable to start a transaction in the given time.
```

I won't get error if the `myCrendentials` only have 12 items. but if the items increased to more than 12, prisma throws the above error.
any idea why this happens?

p.s. increasing the timeout and maxWait didn't help

**edit**:
I think I found the problem.
I am making some queries in prisma middleware.
so it throws this error because somehow the queries inside of middleware are using the main prisma client BUT inside a transaction.
still searching...

Comment: Check https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/10218

Comment: @James I checked the link before asking this question. It didn't help. but my transaction is not very heavy. even if I make a simple update query inside of it, it will throw the error after running more than 12 or 13 transactions at a time.
imagine thousands of users are going to request the API and run the transaction. BOOM :)

Comment: For reference: https://github.com/prisma/prisma/discussions/18573

Comment: @NurulSundarani oh thanks. forgot to submit the answer here :))

Comment: Thanks for sharing the answer here as well! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue.
I had some extra queries inside Prisma middleware. and when I was updating my record inside the transaction, the middleware was making the transaction much heavier than it should be.

so, I came up with creating a util function instead and doing the process inside the transaction directly.
now I can run ~1000 transactions at a time